# Web essentials 2017 not shown in visual studio 2017 toolbars

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, web-essentials

I just downloaded and installed Web essentials 2017 for Visual Studio 2017 from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017). But it doesn't show in VS toolbar or any browser!

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: still not working in my pc

Comment: I actually didn't resolve this issue till nw unfortunately :(

Comment: same issue by me

Comment: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2017/issues/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2017/issues/12 it won't work like on older versions.
You need to do this:

1. Install this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-essentials/mghdcdlpcdiodelbplncnodiiadljhhk
2. To get Inspect and Debug Mode install this additional extension in VisualStudio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserLinkInspector2017

Hope this helps.